# ASP.NET membership db using integrated security problem

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, integrated-security

I published ASP.NET MVC web site to a server on a virtual machine (Hyper-V). SQL Server Express installed on the same server.

The problem is that ASP.Net Membership system doesn't work in integrated mode. When **Web.config** file contains records as follows:

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="MyDBConnectionString" connectionString="data source=vm-1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
```

I get an error when trying to register and login to the site.

If I change connection string this way:

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="MyDBConnectionString" connectionString="data source=vm-1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testdb;User ID=XX;Password=XXXXXXX;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
```

I could register and login without any problem.

What could cause the problem with using ASP.NET membership database in integrated security mode?

Comment: Stupid question(s) 1. The sql server you publish to supports integrated authentication? 2. The account you use for integrated auth has the the same privileges as user `XX`?

Comment: Thanks. I need a help to check it. I can connect with SQL Server Managment studio to SQL Server using windows authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use impersonation you need to grant access to membership objects for the account ASP.NET process is running under. Most likely it's `NETWORKSERVICE`. When you create membership objects with aspnet_regsql.exe, it also creates special roles (like `aspnet_membership_BasicAccess`, etc) with execute permissions to the corresponding SPs. So create a login for `NETWORKSERVICE` account, add a user to your database for that login and grant him one of those `aspnet_` roles.

Try the following script i use as part of my database deployment (must be run as database administrator):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE loginname = N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE')
CREATE LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] FROM WINDOWS
GO
CREATE USER [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] FOR LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]
GO

exec sp_addrolemember 'aspnet_Membership_BasicAccess', 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
GO
exec sp_addrolemember 'aspnet_Roles_BasicAccess', 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
GO
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry but I can not find a Network Service account to create a login for it. Could you give me a hint how I could create such a login?

Comment: Maybe it is something from NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM or NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS that I have as logins in my SQL Server?

Comment: If it's IIS6 or higher (and it probably is) it'll be the account the AppPool is running under.

Comment: no, it should be NETWORK SERVICE (in case of IIS6+) and ASPNET on 5.x.

Comment: Thank you. With the help of your script I successfully performed everything as you suggested: created NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE login, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user for my database, mapped to this login, and granted this user 'aspnet_Membership_BasicAccess' and 'aspnet_Roles_BasicAccess', but my initial problem with Integrated Security remained as it was.

Comment: Well, look like it's not security issue. If you could provide more information like error code/message if would be easier to solve the problem.